# Helm Chart: wordpress deployment problem to reach mariadb

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod, rancher

I'm not able to deploy Wordpress using Rancher Catalog and bitnami/wordpress Helm Chart. MariaDB pod runs fine but wordpress pod errors out as

`ReplicaSet "wordpress-557fcb8469" has timed out progressing.; Deployment does not have minimum availability.`

Also from the wordpress pod logs:

`Error executing 'postInstallation': Failed to connect to wordpress-mariadb:3306 after 36 tries`

and when using the wordpress pod shell:

```
I have no name!@wordpress-557fcb8469-gj585:/$ mysql -h wordpress-mariadb -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'wordpress-mariadb' (-3)
```

but

```
I have no name!@wordpress-557fcb8469-gj585:/$ mysql -h 10.42.0.8 -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 16597
Server version: 10.3.22-MariaDB Source distribution
```

Any clue what can be set wrong?

**Version of Helm and Kubernetes**:

```
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.2.4", GitCommit:"0ad800ef43d3b826f31a5ad8dfbb4fe05d143688", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.12"}
```

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.6", GitCommit:"d32e40e20d167e103faf894261614c5b45c44198", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-05-20T13:16:24Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.3", GitCommit:"2e7996e3e2712684bc73f0dec0200d64eec7fe40", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-05-20T12:43:34Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Pods and services in the `wordpress` namespace:

```
> kubectl get pods,svc -owide --namespace=wordpress
    NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP           NODE            NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
    pod/wordpress-6647794f9b-4mmxd   0/1     Running   20         104m   10.42.0.19   dev-app   <none>           <none>
    pod/wordpress-mariadb-0          1/1     Running   1          26h    10.42.0.14   dev-app   <none>           <none>
    
    NAME                        TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE   SELECTOR
    service/wordpress           LoadBalancer   10.43.91.13     <pending>     80:30158/TCP,443:30453/TCP   26h   app.kubernetes.io/instance=wordpress,app.kubernetes.io/name=wordpress,io.cattle.field/appId=wordpress
    service/wordpress-mariadb   ClusterIP      10.43.178.123   <none>        3306/TCP                     26h   app=mariadb,component=master,io.cattle.field/appId=wordpress,release=wordpress
```

Comment: Looks like a service discovery issue. Can you get a list of services and pods in that namespace and share details? `kubectl get pods,svc -owide`

Comment: @Faheem I have updated OP with requested info. Thanks!

Comment: Please check your system pods and make sure coredns is working correctly. Check it’s logs for any details. The issue may not be related Rancher.

Comment: It came up one of the nodes has problems with CoreDNS (no clue why). In that case should I scrape it or re-register it with the Rancher again and push all images using RKE? Also other 2 nodes are not able to resolve external hostnames.

Answer (score 1):

> Unknown MySQL server host 'wordpress-mariadb' (-3)

The error indicates a DNS failure. Please review your [CoreDNS configuration](https://rancher.com/docs/rke/latest/en/config-options/add-ons/dns/). Check CoreDNS logs for any errors. CoreDNS forwards external queries to the underlined node. Check the node DNS configuration in `/etc/resolv.conf` as well.

Comment: Yes. I was doing that and have opened another issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63622077/kubernetes-coredns-and-problem-with-resolving-hostnames