# Kubernetes: CoreDNS and problem with resolving hostnames

Tags: kubernetes, coredns

I have two kubernetes pods running via Rancher:

#1 - busybox
#2 - dnsutils

From the pod #1:

```
/ # cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 10.43.0.10
search testspace.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5
```

and then

```
/ # nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:    10.43.0.10
Address 1: 10.43.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default'
/ # nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:    10.43.0.10
Address 1: 10.43.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default'
/ # nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:    10.43.0.10
Address 1: 10.43.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      kubernetes.default
Address 1: 10.43.0.1 kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
```

so sometimes it works but mostly not.

then from the pod #2:

```
nameserver 10.43.0.10
search testspace.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5
```

and then:

```
/ # nslookup kubernetes.default
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

/ # nslookup kubernetes.default
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

/ # nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:         10.43.0.10
Address:        10.43.0.10#53

Name:   kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.43.0.1
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

so it mostly doesn't work.

The same problem is when I try to reach any external hostname.

Also tried to troubleshoot based on article from [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/)

ConfigMap:

```
kubectl -n kube-system edit configmap coredns

# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        log
        errors
        health {
          lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
          pods insecure
          fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . "/etc/resolv.conf"
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","data":{"Corefile":".:53 {\n    errors\n    health {\n      lameduck 5s\n    }\n    ready\n    kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {\n      pods insecure\n      fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa\n    }\n    prometheus :9153\n    forward . \"/etc/resolv.conf\"\n    cache 30\n    loop\n    reload\n    loadbalance\n}\n"},"kind":"ConfigMap","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"coredns","namespace":"kube-system"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2020-08-07T19:28:25Z"
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:data:
        .: {}
        f:Corefile: {}
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
    manager: kubectl
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-08-24T19:22:17Z"
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "4118524"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/coredns
  uid: 1f3615b0-9349-4bc5-990b-7fed31879fa2
~
```

Any thought on that?

Comment: What Kubernetes version are you using. Its local env or Cloud env? What about pods in `kube-system` namespace? Any issues, much restarts? Did you configure firewalls?

Comment: Kubernetes is 1.18.3 and it is local. `kube-system` looks stable - only few restarts for `canal` (8) but `coredsn` shows 0. Firewall on the VM where node was created was set by sysops. I can ping external DNS to which but it times out when CoreDNS is trying to reach it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It came up that `kube-dns` service was not able to get CoreDNS pods

```
> kubectl get svc -o wide --namespace=kube-system

NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE   SELECTOR
kube-dns         ClusterIP   10.43.0.10     <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   24d   k8s-app=kube-dns
```

when CoreDNS from one node called directly to the pod was able

```
/ # nslookup google.com 10.42.1.18 
Server:         10.42.1.18
Address:        10.42.1.18#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 172.217.10.110
Name:   google.com
Address: 2607:f8b0:4006:802::200e
```

and another node was not:

```
/ # nslookup google.com 10.42.2.37
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

which may created problem for the `kube-dns` service.

In this case I have decided to rebuild that problematic node and problem went away.